# why the full text search still slow after install the zhparser

Tags: full-text-search, postgresql-13

I have already installed the zhparser to split the chinese words, then I using this sql command to do a full text search:

```
SELECT * 
FROM article a 
WHERE to_tsvector('dolphinzhcfg', title) @@ plainto_tsquery('dolphinzhcfg','经济|文化')
limit 10
```

this sql takes more than 2min to fetch the result, why it still so slow? This sql have already been executed:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION dolphinzhcfg (PARSER = zhparser);

ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION dolphinzhcfg ADD MAPPING FOR n,v,a,i,e,l WITH simple;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finnally found, need to create index for the parser:

```
CREATE INDEX article_title_zh_gin ON public.article USING gin (to_tsvector('dolphinzhcfg'::regconfig, (title)::text));
```